# blazor AuthenticationStateProvider set as not logged in

Tags: blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, asp.net-authentication

I am trying to follow client-side blazers authentication and have a basic setup. I don't find any sample code explaining how to specify that the current user is **not** logged in. I have been trying to do this in the authentication state provider:

```
public class AuthProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        // verify if the user is logged in.
        // if not:
        return Task.FromResult(null);
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(null))`. Both simply throw null pointer functions. On the server it is as simple as calling a `Fail()` function. However, I don't see a `AuthenticationState.Fail()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static ClaimsPrincipal Anonymous
    => new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(Array.Empty<Claim>(), string.Empty));

public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    // if not logged in
    return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(Anonymous));
}
```

I think it's setting the `AuthenticationType` to a blank entry.  I can't get to my code at the moment to assert it.

Comment: odd. this works with `AuthorizeView` not `AuthorizeRouteView`

Comment: What does your `App.razor` look like?  There are a couple of possible reasons.  Do you have the `CascadingAuthenticationState` at the top level? To quote the header info on  the `AuthorizeRouteView` source file  it combines the behaviors of `AuthorizeView` and `RouteView`.... Additionally, this component supplies a cascading parameter of type `Task{AuthenticationState}`.

Comment: this is the app.razor code: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/Socially/blob/master/src/Socially.Website/App.razor. Yes, I was using 
`CascadingAuthenticationState`. Without that, the AuthorizeView doesn't work either

Comment: Need to have a think about this one.   Here's the MS code if you want to try and figure it out - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Authorization/src/AuthorizeRouteView.cs